# How properly download multiple files from Firebase Storage on Android?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-storage

I have a problem with file download from Firebase Storage on Android application. I know the method how to download one image and display it on `ImageView`. But I have a problem when I need to download more than one image in single activity.
I have the names of the files in the `List<String>` and they are for example: **[*`img1, img2`*]**.

#### For files download I have written a method:

```
private void downloadImg(String name) {
    String path = "images/"+name+".png";
    StorageReference ref = storage.getReference().child(path);
    try {
        final File localFile = File.createTempFile("Images", "png");
        ref.getFile(localFile).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener< FileDownloadTask.TaskSnapshot >() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(FileDownloadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(localFile.getAbsolutePath());
                if (bitmap != null) {
                    initImages(bitmap);
                }
            }
        }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                Log.e(Tags.IMAGES, e.getMessage());
            }
        });
    } catch(IOException e) {
        Log.e(Tags.IMAGES, e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

This method downloads a *`.png`* file with given *name* as a parameter and sets it to new `ImageView`.

#### The method to set the image on the ImageView:

(*Problem shouldn't be there*)

```
private void initImages(Bitmap bitmap) {
    int total = imageNames.size();
    int column = 4;
    ImageView image;
    for (int i = 0, c = 0, r = 0; i < total; i++, c++) {
        if (c == column) {
            c = 0;
            r++;
        }
        image = new ImageView(this);
        image.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
        image.setContentDescription(getString(R.string.addImageDescription));
        image.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.bHint));
        image.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        image.setOnClickListener(imageClickListener(bitmap));
        imagesGrid.addView(image, i);
        GridLayout.LayoutParams params = new GridLayout.LayoutParams();
        params.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
        params.height = hw_60;
        params.width = hw_60;
        params.setMargins(padding_5, padding_5, padding_5, padding_5);
        params.columnSpec = GridLayout.spec(c);
        params.rowSpec = GridLayout.spec(r);
        image.setLayoutParams(params);
    }
}
```

This method creates new `ImageView` and sets downloaded `Bitmap` to it.
I am using `downloadImg(name);` method on activity `onCreate()` method like this:

```
for(String name : imageNames) {
    downloadImg(name);
}
```

## Summary and main question:

I have two objects in my Firebase Storage with given names **[*`img1, img2`*]**. Same file names are stored to `List<String>` for getting files by name. In activity `onCreate()` method calls `downloadImg(name)` method for each name. The method downloads the image and sets it to new `ImageView`.
**My problem is that only one of the images will be downloaded and displayed twice.** I have tried some other methods to get the names from list and download the file. So sometimes *img1* appears on both `ImageView`s and sometimes - *img2*. For this method appears only *img1* twice.

*p.s.: I have searched for the answers for this type of problem. There is no possible duplicates.*

Comment: *Before saying that is duplicate read all the description and main question. Thank you.*

Comment: Why do you have a for loop with downloadImg() and then again initImages() with another for loop which gets called multiple times?

Comment: I missed that. I was searching problem only on image download methods. Thank you. That was my bad.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar probs, the localFile var was overwritten by the time the 
download completes and onSuccess wants to use that.
I ended up doing something like this

```
ArrayMap<String, File> localTmpFileArray = new ArrayMap<String, File>();
...
private void populateAvailableImages() {

    populateImageView("firstImpression.jpg", R.id.image_edit_profile_first_impression);
    populateImageView("profileImage1.jpg", R.id.image_profile_1);
    populateImageView("profileImage2.jpg", R.id.image_profile_2);
}
private void populateImageView(final String serverSideImageName, final int
        imageViewResourceId) {

    File imageLocalTmpFile = null;

    try {
        imageLocalTmpFile = File.createTempFile(serverSideImageName, "jpg");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.w("ops", e);
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Could not create local file. Storage " +
                "full??", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    localTmpFileArray.put(serverSideImageName, imageLocalTmpFile);

    StorageReference storageRef;
    storageRef = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference();
    StorageReference imageRef = storageRef.child("users/" + FauthUtils.getUserId() + "/" +
            serverSideImageName);
    imageRef.getFile(localTmpFileArray.get(serverSideImageName)).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<FileDownloadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(FileDownloadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
            ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(imageViewResourceId);
            imageView.setImageURI(Uri.fromFile(localTmpFileArray.get(serverSideImageName)));
        }
    }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception exception) {
            // Handle failed download
            // ...
        }
    });
}
```